# Web service returns application/json but browser displays HTML

Tags: php, json, slim

My REST Web Service returns a JSON response using the following code:

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($languages,128);
```

However, when I test the service on my browser - it renders the JSON as HTML. If I inspect the source, I can see HTML tags and everything. What's causing this and how do I fix this?

[image: Raw source code]

[image: Response Headers]

Thanks.

P.S.: I'm using the Slim Framework, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Could you attach a thumbnail?

Comment: Also, are you inspecting the selection source or the raw source code?

Comment: @RahilWazir: I've attached a thumbnail.

Comment: @Scott: I'm inspecting the raw source code and the Response details.

Comment: Try viewing source by pressing `CTRL+U`. Inspecting elements from developer console does include `html/body/head` tags

Comment: @RahilWazir: Yeah, there are no HTML tags when I view source by `Ctrl-U` but I'm still confused as to why the response header says that the Content-Type is `text/html` when it's supposed to be `application/json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a browser extension installed that presents JSON as a nicely formatted, human readable HTML document.